# how to access result of method in vue

Tags: vue.js

I want to pass a result of a method to params. Here's my code

```
<template>
    <router-link
        v-bind:to="{
            name: 'faq-page',
            params: { id: selectedCategory },
        }"
    >
         <li><a @click="findCategory(eachQuestion.id, faqData)">{{eachQuestion.question}}</a></li>
    </router-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            selectedCategory: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        findCategory(id, list) {
            const x = //function here
            if (x) {
             return this.selectedCategory = this.x.slug;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The idea of this code is, whenever a user click the `<li>`, the method will be executed to find `x.slug`. Then I want to pass the `x.slug` in the params. I believe I did something wrong with the code. What's the correct way to pass the method value to the params? Thanks so much.

Comment: this.category is not defined in the data. From where do you get it?

Comment: ah sorry, I mistyped my question. Fixed it already! @NoyGafni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should not return the a value, and x is a local variable so you shouldn’t use this.x:

```js
methods: {
        findCategory(id, list) {
            const x = //function here
            if (x) {
             this.selectedCategory = x.slug;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see.. I've tried it but it still doesn't work. Is this line valid `params: { id: selectedCategory }`?

Comment: It suppose to work but maybe try return the hole route to object in a computed property and see if it works

Comment: Solved it! Thank u so much!!

Comment: so the solution was using it in computed property??

Comment: no, my list wasn't imported properly so i had to fix that one. but your answer is true and it helped solve my problem!